# ¿como actualizo el navegador Firefox automaticamente cada que realizo cambios en mi documento html o css?

Tags: firefox, firefox-webextensions

lo que quiero es una forma de hacer lo mismo que hace "LivePage" en chrome pero para firefox 
que básicamente es "carga de nuevo recursos de sitios web tales como CSS, HTML y JavaScript cuando cambian en el servidor."

Comment: Usa este software https://prepros.io/

Comment: Si estás trabajando con el IDE visual studio code, existe una extensión llamada Live Server, actualiza la página automáticamente cuando guardas el archivo